# Пустое пространство под ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно сделать так, чтобы внутри`ScrollView` был `ListView`, и он (`ListView`) скролился вместе `ScrollView`. Вот как я реализовал, но между `ListView` и третьим контейнером(Footer) большое пространство появилось.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**main_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".Details.Book.BookDetails"
android:background="@color/fragment_bg">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

<View android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/view5" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout16">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_top_layout"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/leftPadding"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/rightPadding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/rightPadding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/leftPadding">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textviewTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="@string/buy_det_pass_txt"
                    android:textColor="@color/background_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout9"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/leftPadding"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/rightPadding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/rightPadding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/leftPadding">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout9"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/textMargin"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView43"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/buy_det_fullname"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainSmallSize" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvFullName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:text="Medium Text"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/textMargin"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView35"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/buy_det_gender"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainSmallSize" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvGender"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:text="Medium Text"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/textMargin"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView37"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/buy_det_ticknumber"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainSmallSize" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvTickNumber"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:text="Medium Text"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout6"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/textMargin"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView39"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/buy_det_issdate"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainSmallSize" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvIssDate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:text="Medium Text"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/textMargin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/textMargin"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout16" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listView">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_top_layout"
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout9"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/leftPadding"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/leftPadding"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/rightPadding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/rightPadding">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/buy_det_cost_txt"
                    android:id="@+id/tvFromTo"
                    android:textColor="@color/background_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout9"
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout10"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/rightPadding"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/rightPadding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/leftPadding"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/leftPadding">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout9"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/textMargin" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/buy_det_fare"
                        android:id="@+id/textView43"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainSmallSize" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Medium Text"
                        android:id="@+id/tvFare"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/textMargin">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/buy_det_taxes"
                        android:id="@+id/textView35"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainSmallSize" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Medium Text"
                        android:id="@+id/tvTaxes"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/textMargin">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/buy_det_service_fees"
                        android:id="@+id/textView37"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainSmallSize" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Medium Text"
                        android:id="@+id/tvFees"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout6"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/textMargin">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/buy_det_total_price"
                        android:id="@+id/textView39"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainSmallSize" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Medium Text"
                        android:id="@+id/tvTotPrice"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout7"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout15"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/textMargin" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/buy_det_form_of_pay"
                        android:id="@+id/textView54"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainSmallSize" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Medium Text"
                        android:id="@+id/tvPayment"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
ListUtils.setDynamicHeight(listView);
```

**ListUtils class**

```
public static class ListUtils {
    public static void setDynamicHeight(ListView mListView) {
        ListAdapter mListAdapter = mListView.getAdapter();
        if (mListAdapter == null) {
            return;
        }
        int height = 0;
        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mListView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        for (int i = 0; i < mListAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = mListAdapter.getView(i, null, mListView);
            listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            height += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mListView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = height + (mListView.getDividerHeight() * (mListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        mListView.setLayoutParams(params);
        mListView.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как устранить?

Comment: Не стоит пытаться даже такое городить - подумайте как вам иначе сделать то, что вы хотите без оборачивания ListView в ScrollView

Comment: Скажите, вы сами как то разбираетесь во всех этих `textView39` и `relativeLayout10`? Понять, что для чего и зачем решительно невозможно же.

Comment: pavlofff, я их не использую, поэтому ID не переименованы.

Comment: ЮрийСПб, не совсем понял

Comment: Если id не используется - незачем их назначать, только класс R забиваете бесполезной информацией

Comment: pavlofff, то есть из-за них могут быть проблемы?

Comment: Не то чтобы явные проблемы, лишний и не нужный расход ресурсов. У вас некоторые id используются для связывания виджетов в разметке `RelativeLayout`-ов и трудно понять, что там с чем связывается из-за этих всех `linearLayout10`, вот в чем проблема. Вы в визуальном редакторе верстаете что ли?

Comment: Да в визуальном (иногда в ручную). Огромное спасибо за информацию, если честно я и не знал про расход ресурсов.

Comment: Тут у вас основная проблема в том, что если в центральном списке будет пунктов больше, чем войдет на экран, то скролится ничего не будет из конфликта `ScrollView` и `ListView`/ Поскольку у вас небольшое количество элементов, рекомендую программное наполнение нужного количества пунктов с маршрутами в обычный контейнер, а не `ListView`

Comment: А расстояние это видимо из-за каких то ошибок подсчета высоты `ListView`. Чем вас не устраивает `wrap_content`, он так же устанавливает высоту только в необходимую, для того чтобы все вошло.

Comment: Таким образом исчезает пространство, но `ListView` показывает только первый `item`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Может кому поможет! Вместо `ListView` использовал `NonScrollListView`.

```
public class NonScrollListView extends ListView {

public NonScrollListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
    params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Уберите `ScrollView` и оставьте только `ListView`, но добавьте ему Header и Footer - addHeaderView(), addFooterView(). 
Это надо делать перед `setAdapter()`.

См. [пример](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/114-urok-55-header-i-footer-v-spiskah-headerviewlistadapter)

Comment: Так делал, но так не получается вставить общий `background` центральному контейнеру.

Comment: В смысле? Какому контейнеру? Серенький фон или рамку?

Comment: Контейнер маршрута!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте взять обычный LinearLayout. В него вложить ТехтView "Пассажир",  ListView "Маршрут". Установите ListView атрибут android:layout_weight="1" и ТехтView "Итого". LinearLayout установите необходимый background.

Comment: Без ScrollView ???

Comment: да, без scrollview. когда на экране появится необходимость скролить, listview сам будет это делать